# How convert/put the char* variable into struct sockaddr?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, type-conversion

Hi

I have a problem with giving a name to socket by a program parameter.
I tried do it in many ways, some conversions (strcpy function)etc. but in the best option it gives me a one letter from my name. How can I convert/put it into that structure?

```
void socket_out(char* name)
{
int listfd;
int connfd;

listfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(listfd == -1)
    exit(-1);

struct sockaddr saddr = {AF_UNIX, name};
socklen_t saddrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr) + 6;
bind(listfd, &saddr, saddrlen);
```

And error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
>        struct sockaddr saddr = {AF_UNIX, name};

Comment: You need to use strcpy function (or similar)

Comment: I used it, but it doesnt works. Maybe i wrong put it in struct sockaddr saddr? When i use a pointer, i got one letter.

Comment: please try something like https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=6dXcVL3HKamt8wfWoYLoCw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=struct+sockaddr+saddr+site:github.com . You will find examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just realized my previous answer was out of topic, as you seem to use Unix Domain Sockets, not TCP/IP sockets.

The problem is that you should never use `struct sockaddr` directly, but rather one of its "specializations", in this case `struct sockaddr_un`, and then cast it at the last minute. Have a look at the following example:

```
unsigned int s, s2;
struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
int len;

s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(local.sun_path, "/home/beej/mysocket");
unlink(local.sun_path);
len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len);
```

Taken from the excellent *Beej's Guide to Unix IPC*: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html

Answer (score 0):

you are tying to initialize a structure there, but the second parameter is not of type char*, but of type char[].
See the definition for struct [sockaddr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html):

```
The <sys/socket.h> header shall define the sockaddr structure that includes at least the following members:

sa_family_t  sa_family  Address family. 
char         sa_data[]  Socket address (variable-length data).
```

To get around that, you have to use strcpy/strncpy for the second parameter:

```
struct sockaddr saddr;
saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 
strncpy(saddr.sun_path, name, UNIX_PATH_MAX);
addr.sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX - 1] = '\0';
```